# Inline numa função recursiva infinita

Tags: c, c++, recursão, inline

O que acontece com o programa se eu declarar uma função recursiva infinita *inline*?

Comment: Uma [recursão infinita resulta em comportamento indefinido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905155/is-this-infinite-recursion-ub), então não importa muito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na teoria ou prática? Na teoria poderia quebrar o compilador, mas todo compilador que se preza fará o *inline* de forma limitada. Não compensa fazer mais que 4 otimizações (isso é detalhe de implementação), depois disso é melhor fazer a chamada sem o *inline*. Na verdade é possível que considere nem fazer nada.